# How to trim this text in Python?

Tags: python

My script returns text in a weird way, and i need to trim it so it becomes readable.

This is an example of the return text:

```
b'\r\nR5#'b'e'b'n'b'\r\n'b'R5#'b'c'b'o'b'n'b'f'b' t'b'\r\n'b'Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.\r\nR5(config)#'b'h'b'o'b's'b't'b'n'b'a'b'm'b'e'b' 'b'R'b'5'b'\r\n'b'R5(config)#'
```

This is how the text should appear, with line breaks and without the 'b'\r\n:

```
R5#en
R5#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.
R5(config)#hostname R5
R5(config)#
```

How can i trim/split this correctly in Python?

Comment: Is it the content of a variable? How did you examine that result - did you try to `print` the said variable?

Comment: Please show the code that output the text. Is it a `print`, `repr` or `str` call? What is the text? `str` or `bytes` or something else entirely?

Comment: See [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is bytes. You can get the desired output by decoding it into a string.

```
s = b'\r\nR5#'b'e'b'n'b'\r\n'b'R5#'b'c'b'o'b'n'b'f'b' t'b'\r\n'b'Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.\r\nR5(config)#'b'h'b'o'b's'b't'b'n'b'a'b'm'b'e'b' 'b'R'b'5'b'\r\n'b'R5(config)#'

print(s.decode('utf-8'))
```

You can find more information from this related question:
[Convert bytes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: I'm not sure that OP has provided enough information to justify the first assertion.

Comment: Hi. Thank you all for your quick help.
You are correct, and i'm sorry. I can decode it and it works perfectly in python's shell. But this text will be shown in an html page. And it doesn't break if i simply decode it. So i'd like to trim it and split it correctly, so i can then print each line to html.

Comment: The code is posted here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901968/paramiko-split-lines-in-html-page
But i'm thinking of an alternative way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

python3

```
s=b'\r\nR5#'b'e'b'n'b'\r\n'b'R5#'b'c'b'o'b'n'b'f'b' t'b'\r\n'b'Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.\r\nR5(config)#'b'h'b'o'b's'b't'b'n'b'a'b'm'b'e'b' 'b'R'b'5'b'\r\n'b'R5(config)#'
s=s.strip().decode("utf-8")
print(s)
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images if not really necessary. You can paste the return value if your solution in the same way like your code; often it's commented to separate it visually from the code.

Comment: @SpghttCd sure, I will follow your advice. Thanks